# Arrayformula inside an array in google sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have the following formula in google sheets which works perfectly in the row 3.

```
=ArrayFormula(if(len($A$3:$A),vlookup($A$3:$A,'All records in progress'!A2:BE,{57,6,7,8,9,10,11,13,14,31,32,33},FALSE),""))
```

However, I would like to have the formula in the row 2 with the header so I was trying to create something like this:

```
={"Header"; ArrayFormula(if(len($A$3:$A),vlookup($A$3:$A,'All records in progress'!A2:BE,{57,6,7,8,9,10,11,13,14,31,32,33},FALSE),""))}
```

So I could have the word Header in the first row and the formula from the next row onwards. However, my formula is not working. Do you know if how I could achieve this?

Looking forward to your reply.

Cheers,

Answer (score 1):

your vlookup returns 12 columns so you need:

```
={{"Header","","","","","","","","","","",""}; 
 ARRAYFORMULA(IF(LEN(A3:A),
 IFNA(VLOOKUP(A3:A, 'All records in progress'!A2:BE, 
 {57,6,7,8,9,10,11,13,14,31,32,33}, 0)), ))}
```